# Layout TextView Hint not always showing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, hint

I have 4 textview, all numbers. The first one "#" is the hint and it shows up on my 4.2 and 2.2. The next three are "Hours, Minutes, Seconds" respectively and the hint shows up on 4.2 but not 2.2. Here is my xml for the them.

First Textview has # and the next three will say Hour, Minute, Second.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainBodyScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/perDistanceLayout"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainBodyLinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/default_distance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/distanceEntryLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/distanceText"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/default_number_hint"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    >
                </EditText>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:entries="@array/spinner2_array" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/default_in"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/timeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hourText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="@string/default_hours"
                    android:inputType="number" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/minuteText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="@string/default_minutes"
                    android:inputType="number" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/secondText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="@string/default_seconds"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/paceclearButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:minHeight="32dip"
                android:text="@string/default_clear"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow setting `center_horizontal` value in the `android:gravity` is causing issues in Android 2.2 in displaying the hint.

Remove `center_horizontal` from the value of `android:gravity` to display the hint.

Comment: that worked thank you. i have another quesiton relating to those 4 edittexts. when im in the first one "#" it prompts the numeric keyboard with "next" being an option, to go to next field obviously, but when i get to any of the next three it just says done and wont let me go to next field with the "next" button.    ie. "#" -NEXT- "Hours" -Done- "Minute" -Done- "Second" -Done-

Comment: never mind, i got it. Add this to the desired Editext for anyone who reads this later.    android:imeOptions="actionNext"